# How to configure Web Deploy 3.5 EncryptWebConfig rule handler?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, msdeploy, webdeploy

We are wanting to setup publishing via the Web Deploy method in Visual Studio 2013. I've installed Web Deploy 3.5 on the destination web server and it's deploying properly.

We'd like to also use Web Deploy 3.5's EncryptWebConfig rule handler to encrypt our web.config files post-publish as described here: http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2013/07/09/webdeploy-3-5-rtw.aspx, which gives a command line example. However this is not an option in the "Publish Web" Wizard > Web Deploy Method , nor do I know how to add in that rule through directly modifying the .pubxml PublishProfile... Or is the EncryptWebConfig a rule I setup somehow in IIS on the server?

I was unable to find any further documentation on this rule anywhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had also tweeted a guy who works for the Visual Studio Web team and he came through with this answer:

Add the property `<MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>true</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>` to your .pubxml file

I figured it'd be like this, but previously could not find any references to the proper tag name, MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule, anywhere.

Comment: This is working..sometimes. other times I get "Web deployment task failed. (Failed to encrypt destination web.config: web.config.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FAILED_TO_ENCRYPT_WEB_CONFIG.)"  the link gives no help. I can't figure out why I get this error. I've double checked permissions to the server web folder and all looks fine.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, just figured it out. please see my answer in the link below. In short, I added my deploy user as a local Administrator on the server that I was deploying to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406561/asp-net-msdeployenablewebconfigencryptrule-fail-to-encrypt-web-config/29107733#29107733