# asp.net MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule fail to encrypt web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added `<MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>true</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>` to .pubxml file in order to encrypt web config file. However, when publishing, i got the following error. I do not know whether there is extra setting needed in the web.config file other than inserting `<MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>true</MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule>` in .pubxml

Error:
Web deployment task failed.(Fail to encrypt destination web.config. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FAILED_TO_ENCRYPT_WEB_CONFIG.)

Note: #ERROR_FAILED_TO_ENCRYPT_WEB_CONFIG does not appears anywhere on the given link.

How could i resolve this error? (note: i do not wish to pre-encrypt the web.config file locally before publishing it)

Comment: I too have this same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seem to be that MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule doesn't work with MVC project that have multiple web.config files. Typically MVC project has Views/Web.Config file.  This seems like a bug with MSDeploy.
My Workaround is to have a post deployment powershell script to perform same command on the destination server. See http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets

Powershell Script Sample:

```
    Add-PSSnapin WDeploySnapin3.0
    $cmd = '%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASPNET_REGIIS.exe -{0} {1} "{2}"' -f 'pef', 'connectionStrings', $destinationFolder
    New-WDPublishSettings -UserId $UserName -Password $Password -ComputerName $destination -AllowUntrusted -FileName server.publishsettings -AgentType MSDepSvc -Site $Website
    Invoke-WDCommand -Command $cmd  -DestinationPublishSettings server -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same message too.
I looked in the Web Deployment logs in the Event Viewer > Microsoft Web Deploy. The Exception it was giving me was:

ERROR_FAILED_TO_ENCRYPT_WEB_CONFIG
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: Failed to encrypt destination web.config: ....  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FAILED_TO_ENCRYPT_WEB_CONFIG. ---> **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists.**

Googling this led me to this answer from "Just TFS": [Release Management Agent not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643161/release-management-agent-not-connecting)

Which said "The Deployer user (\) does not have access to the crypto store. On the server where the deployment agent is installed, navigate to this folder %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys and give read/write access to \. –  Just TFS Sep 3 '14 at 12:08"

So I attempted to give my MS Deployer user account read/write to that MachineKeys folder but it denied me access to do so. I ended up adding the deployer user account as a local Administrator and that did the trick.

Was able to deploy with it encrypting the web.config file successfully to the server.